# Утиная типизация = динамическая типизация?

Tags: любой-язык, типизация, динамическая-типизация

Не могу найти явный ответ. Утиная типизация это тоже самое, что динамическая типизация, это лишь один из вариантов динамической типизации или что-то третье?

Comment: я не могу назвать себя крупным специалистом, но, по моему, динамическая типизация - это механизм, используемыйв языке, для динамического получания типов переменных. А утиная типизация - это концепция, используемая при построении иерархии классов, то есть штука из области ООП. Просто названия похожие.

Comment: полез разбираться, нашел умную статью. Короткий ответ: нет, это разные штуки. Ссылка: https://web.archive.org/web/20201111201602/http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Давайте разберемся по-порядку.

**Динамическая типизация** означает, что вам не нужно явно определять тип переменной на этапе написания кода, интерпретатор попытается самостоятельно определить тип этой переменной *во время исполнения программы* (динамически) исходя из его значения.

**Утиная типизация** означает, что для работы программы нам важен не сам тип объекта, а его функциональная составляющая.
То есть, если некий объект содержит в себе необходимые атрибуты и методы, то это означает, что он удовлетворяет нашим требованиям.

Отсюда [известная фраза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82):

> Если нечто выглядит как утка, плавает как утка и крякает как утка, то
> это, вероятно, и есть утка.

Другими словами, за утку мы считаем что угодно, что умеет плавать как утка и крякать как утка, и, хотя, на самом деле это может оказаться совсем не утка, а какой-нибудь гусь, нас это не должно волновать, поскольку для нашей задачи объект реализует весь необходимый функционал.

Не могу не вставить потрясающую картинку, которая прекрасным образом иллюстрирует вышесказанное :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Приведу простой пример утиной типизации:

В языке `Python` есть функция `str()` для перевода объекта в строку :

```
type(1) -> <class 'int'>
type(str(1)) -> <class 'str'>
```

Как она на самом деле работает?
Если упростить, то это выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
def str(obj):
    return obj.__str__
```

"Под капотом" вызывается "магический" метод `__str__`, который и реализует требуемый функционал.

Но тут есть нюанс, если мы напишем так:

```
class A:
    ...

a = A()
str(a) # <__main__.A object at 0x0000019E62D27C10>
```

То, никакой ошибки не возникнет, хочется спросить - почему? Ведь класс `A` не реализует магический метод `__str__`.

Тут дело в том, что все объекты в языке `Python` по умолчанию наследуются от базового класса `object`, а сам класс `object` в свою очередь уже реализует магический метод `__str__`, поэтому требуемое поведение будет взято из базового класса.

Суть этого примера в том, чтобы показать - функции `str()` не важно объект какого типа вы передадите ей в качестве аргумента, главное, чтобы этот объект умел конвертироваться в строку (реализовывал магический метод `__str__`).

Но `object`, конечно же, реализует не все магические методы и если написать, например:

```
class A:
    ...

a = A()
b = A()
print(a + b)
```

То тут мы уже получим исключение `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'A'`, поскольку ни класс `A`, ни базовый класс `object` не реализуют магический метод для сложения объектов `__add__`.

---

### Динамическая и утиная типизация - это одно и то же?

И хотя утиная типизация используется в основном в динамически типизированных языках, существуют примеры и **статической утиной типизации** - это, например, шаблоны С++:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T x) { x.foo(); }
```

В этой функции есть ограничение только на тип переменной, но нет ограничения на то, что объект этого типа должен реализовывать метод `foo()`, но это будет проверено **во время компиляции** (а не динамически).

Также, несмотря на то, что все динамически типизированные ООП языки поддерживают утиную типизацию можно придумать пример (почти бесполезный в практике), когда язык будет динамически типизированным, но без утиной типизации: например, `PHP` с ограничением на базовые типы, без использования ООП.

---

### Какой вывод?

> Утиная типизация это тоже самое, что динамическая типизация, это лишь
> один из вариантов динамической типизации или что-то третье?

Динамическая типизация и утиная типизация - **это не одно и то же** и они не являются вариантами друг друга, а вполне могут существовать по отдельности.

**Динамическая типизация** - это функциональность языка, при который типы переменных вычисляются динамически на этапе выполнения программы.

**Утиная типизация** полагается на реализацию объектом необходимых методов, а тип самого объекта не проверяется.

Comment: можно ли утверждать, что обобщение типов - это утиный механизм?

Comment: @Anatol нет, дженерики в Java, например, не реализуют утиную типизацию